# App Store testers use an actual test environment?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I've got a new application that we can't allow the App Store testers to go against the production web service.  Instead, we've got a test environment setup with a different URL for the web service.

I've tried to have them alter the application's plist file to switch the value of a specially-named entry.  That didn't work out - they either weren't able to alter the file or didn't know what I was talking about.

What is the best way to have the App Store testers switch the application into a test mode? We obviously don't want people who download from the store to be able to do this.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the live system!? If it passes the test, you will start with the live system anyhow, no?

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't possible to have appropriate test data in the production environment.  The test environment is identical to production but it is our sandbox for such things.

Answer (score 1):

The review team won't alter apps.  To alter the plist, you would have to resubmit the app and then release it as approved.

Have your production server (or the load balancers, etc., in front of it) redirect all network traffic from the submitted app to your test server before submitting the app.  Then, after the app is approved, but before you release the app for download, (re)configure your network for regular production use.

If needed, modify any test apps used by existing production test users to use some alternate temporary path around this redirection.

Answer (score 0):

App Store reviewers does run your app from an iPad. If your app requires online access, you must provide username and password for evaluation. Review will take longer but they do log on using your account and see what's available in the app.

They need the production environment considering it's the environment users will be using. I don't think the review team will accept a switch to a test environment.

If you don't do this, your app will be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Then just give them a testaccount. If you're logged in via the testaccount, redirect all requests to your testenvironment.